# prevent screenshot in ios device

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I want to prevent screenshot in the ios app and I did this, now I want to test this feature in the simulator but I have no way to test the screenshot in the simulator
Does anyone know how to test it ?

Comment: do `cmd+s` when you are on simulator.

Comment: not work 
cmd+s Takes a photo but my functions aren't firing.
in real device work but in simulator not